# Tools for understanding Abstract Mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-software

I want to explore the concepts of Groups, Rings and Fields for practical application.

1. Are there *beginner-friendly* tools available to *simplify*, *accelerate*, *verify* the understanding of concepts in `Abstract` mathematics?
2. Are these tools publicly available? *free* of cost?
3. Do they provide some kind of *Visualization*?

My interests are in *Abstract Algebra*, but I also want to use a generalized tool that can handle other pure mathematics like Geometry, Number Theory and Mathematical Analysis.

<sub>*Preferred Tools: Software that can run on Android (or) Ubuntu (or) Windows*</sub>

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. But I think if you're just starting to learn abstract algebra, there will be at most isolated instances in which computer tools can really enhance your understanding. Sage is free all-purpose math software. It does some number theory computations.

Answer (score 4):

Limited to groups (and fairly basic at that), but pretty visual is [Group Explorer](http://groupexplorer.sourceforge.net/).

I think it covers groups up to normal subgroups and homomorphisms, but it's been a while since I played with it. It runs on Windows (and Linux if you know how to compile stuff).

Comment: It's too old. Last update at 2009. It depend on Qt3, however Qt already update to Qt5.

Comment: No. In its new incarnation, it's being actively developed: https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt that it is possible the make a *beginner-friendly, simplifying, accelerating, verifying, visualizating etc... tool for practical application*. You still have some work to do in any way. And some things are not made to be visualized (well I do not stop you to try) but even after a while of studying it I do not have a clue how to visualize e.g. ideals of rings or normal subgroups etc. Of course you get a feeling for everything you work with - provided you do it for long and deep enough.

But the following programs are free and I think might help you.

- For group theory I recommend [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/)
- As general CAS I can recommend [WxMaxima](https://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/)
- For numerical purposes and matrix calculations there is [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (Make sure to get GNUplot)
- A very limited software used for visualizations in algebraic geometry is [SURFER](http://imaginary.org/program/surfer)
- For statistical purposes (even just fiddling around) [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is the way to go.
- For 2D geometry and Plotting curves and playing with parameters I highly recommend [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/)
- I did not have experience with it myself, but I heard a lot of good things about [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)

Comment: [*Desmos*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is a far more powerful tool for graphing implicit equations than *GeoGebra*, since the latter only accepts polynomial ones.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is not particularly good for implicit equations, but it's strength in my opinino is the ability to do 2d constructions (like straightedge/compass but somewhat more sophisticated) and the nice faders for altering parameters. But I didn't know about desmos, really looks nice and is loading pretty fast!