# Book which fleshes theory by case studies in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I want to enrich my intuition of the structures studied in Abstract Algebra by going through case studies of them. So, for example, I want some example to be worked through, and in process, the theory to be developed for it.

For example, something like page-298 of Gallian Helpful (section on weird-dice). Also, I liked the sections on graph theory by Kennth H Rosen in his book of discrte mathematics.

Comment: There are many, many types of algebraic structures that have been studied. Please clarify which you have interest in, and what you mean by a "case study" (assume readers don't have access to said books).

Comment: Hmm I have described it in the first paragraph and I gave explicit examples from standard books in the second. Is there some part particularly ambiguous?  I want to study the structures which come in an abstract algebra book at an UG level. So for example Groups, Rings, Fields etc. @BillDubuque

Comment: How does a "case study" of a group, ring or field differ from the common studies already in (first) courses in algebra? It is far from clear what you seek.

Comment: Hmm, so what I want is like, the book presents an example question, and now to solve that question, it develops the abstract algebra theory to describe various parts and hence end at solution of the problem

Comment: Usually books seperate the problems and the theory. So, the theory is developed in total generality without any reference to concrete examples and then later in chapter example is shown. I want something which takes a much less pure approach by bringing the theory out of the examples rather than examples out of the theory if it makes sense

Comment: Could you please write a fleshed out answer on the idea you are suggesting ? I think it maybe what I am looking for @Moo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding your request, you are looking for ways to make abstract algebra theory computational to build intuition and experience.

There are many resources that have been created to support this using [*Computer Algebra Systems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Examples include professional packages like Magma, Mathematica, Maple and open source packages like GAP, Pari/GP, FriCAS, SAGE and others.

Many books and course materials have been written to go along with these systems and to help provide a more intuitive, exploratory, and experimental approach to abstract algebra and any math area. Examples include

- Abstract Algebra, An Interactive Approach - Second Edition (many wonderful examples to further explore using SAGE and others) by  William Paulsen
- http://abstract.pugetsound.edu/sage-aata.html (each section has SAGE exercises and examples), also see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Quickstarts/Abstract-Algebra.html
- Algebra for Applications (uses GAP) by Arkadii Slinko
- Group Explorer - https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/index.html
- Learning Abstract Algebra with GAP - [https://mathstat.slu.edu/~rainbolt/FullManual8th.pdf](https://mathstat.slu.edu/%7Erainbolt/FullManual8th.pdf)
- http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/ - used to study polynomial rings, especially Gröbner bases
- [*SINGULAR*](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) - used to study polynomial rings
- [*CoCoA System*](http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/) - for Computations in Commutative Algebra
- Applications of Abstract Algebra with Maple and MATLAB, Second Edition by Richard Klima, Neil Sigmon, Ernest Stitzinger
- Algebra, A Computational Introduction by John Scherk uses Mathematica and Maple
- Abstract Algebra: A Computational Approach by Charles C. Sims  recommends using APL
- Visual Group Theory by Nathan Carter
- Geometries and groups, by Nikulin and Shafarevich
- Groups and Symmetry by Mark A. Armstrong
- [*Abstract Algebra: Examples and Applications*](http://abstractalgebra.altervista.org/) by Justin Hill, Chris Thron, et al.
- Abstract Algebra: An Inquiry Based Approach by Jonathan K. Hodge, Steven Schlicker, Ted Sundstrom
- ...many others

There are also useful resources to have handy like

- For group theory, Tim Dokchitser has a database called [*GroupNames*](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/). This provides presentations, important subgroups and quotients, and character tables.
- [*Group Tables and Subgroup Diagrams*](https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/groups/groups.html)

You might also like to explore

- [What computer algebra system or package for abstract algebra best suits me?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111267/what-computer-algebra-system-or-package-for-abstract-algebra-best-suits-me)
- [computer program-software for galois](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741962/computer-program-software-for-galois)
- [Tools for understanding Abstract Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028215/tools-for-understanding-abstract-mathematics)
- [How do I sell out with abstract algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365005/how-do-i-sell-out-with-abstract-algebra)
- [Differences between GAP and PARI/GP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261000/differences-between-gap-and-pari-gp)
- [Novel approaches to elementary number theory and abstract algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947239/novel-approaches-to-elementary-number-theory-and-abstract-algebra)
- [Good abstract algebra books for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study)
- ...and others.

Comment: Thanks the group theory books sounds useful. The abstract algebra book in second link Idts is available.

Comment: http://abstract.pugetsound.edu/sage-aata.html the book is not

Comment: http://abstract.pugetsound.edu/download.html ?

Comment: My mistake. Thank you @Mooo