# Recommended first abstract algebra book for self study

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I'm searching a first book on abstract algebra for self study because here, in Catalonia, we have to do an essay on a theme, like a Final Work Degree on a small scale, and I thought that will be interesting to do it about abstract algebra as the theory and some application where I really do something and contribute to mathematics (or something like that). The date limit is December, but I have to get it mainly finished at September-October, so the time of researching and writing the work is limited. I'm on 1st Bachillerato (I'm 17 years old) and I have learned calculus on 1 and some of 2 variables, mainly partial derivatives, and I have a bit of experience on logic, sets and proofs.

I've seen these books, but i'm not really concerned if this books are adequate for my level. Any suggestion is well received!! (My idea is buy two or three of them if it's needed)

- Delgado de la Mata, F.; Fuertes Fraile, C.; Xambò Descamps, S.: Introducción al algebra 2da Edición (This is in Spanish)
- T. W. Hungerford, Abstract Algebra, Brooks/Cole, 2013.
- Gallian, J., Contemporary Abstract Algebra
- Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications (2019)
- Lee, Gregory T. Abstract algebra
- A Book on Abstract Algebra C.Pinter

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-a-high-schooler-self-studying-abstract-algebra?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study, also Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra. Lastly, you might like to review https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394631/book-which-fleshes-theory-by-case-studies-in-abstract-algebra/4394667#4394667

Answer (score 1):

*A First Course in Abstract Algebra* by John B. Fraleigh, 7e.

Comment: Was going to be my answer. I found the book very approachable.